# Knockout.js - Prevent change event binding to trigger when setting the value through the observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a DropDownList with the following bindings:

```
<select data-bind="value: DropDownValue, event: { change: OnChange }">
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    /* and more */
</select>
```

The OnChange event is fired correctly when the user select a different value from the DropDownList.

The event is also fired when updating the value of the observable property using `viewModel.DropDownValue(1)`.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to trigger the change event ONLY when the user sets the value through the UI.

Is it possible to block the change event when updating the value through the observable?

This is the JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/5ex5j7jL/3/

Comment: Any particular reason you don't use the `options` binding?

Comment: So I don't know why do you have to change the value inside your model while you don't want to ? your example has an error here is non-error example https://jsfiddle.net/5ex5j7jL/1/

Comment: @cl3m - I use the `value` binding because the DropDownList is already rendered on the HTML with all the necessary options. With the `options` binding, you have to provide an array of objects and let knockout create the HTML for you.

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle example.
@Matt.k - I want to change the model value, I don't want the change event to be triggered when I do it. (only when the user update the value through the UI)

Comment: looks like one way to do it is to use the `isTrusted` property of the `event` object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like one way to do it is to use [the `isTrusted` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) of the `event` object (`true` when the event was generated by a user action, `false` when generated by a script):

```
self.OnChange = function(viewModel, event) {
  if(event.isTrusted) {
    console.log("from dropdown");
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("NOT from dropdown");
    // do something
  }
};
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ex5j7jL/4/)

**EDIT**

Of course, you have to implement some king of mechanism if you want to prevent the user from changing the dropdown via the UI:

```
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.DropDownValue = ko.observable();
    self._original = null;

    self.OnChange = function(viewModel, event) {
      if(event.isTrusted) {
        // rollback the viewModel value to the old one
        viewModel.DropDownValue(self._original)
        return false
      } else {
        // keep a reference to the latest value for later rollback
        self._original = ko.unwrap(viewModel.DropDownValue)
      }
    };
};
```

See this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ex5j7jL/7/)

Comment: The `isTrusted` property is the way to go. But event passed to that function is a `jQuery.event` and does not expose directly the `isTrusted` property. We need therfore, use `event.originalEvent.isTrusted`

Comment: The property was exposed in the fiddle. I was sure there was a compatibility trick, well done finding it out!